# What is the return value of a int type function that return a int value from query

Tags: c#

Below is my code. I want 'int' type function that will return 'int' value.Query in this code return an 'int' value but in this code what will be the return value? I can't write return get_number here. Then what will I do?

My code :

```
    public int CheckMatch(CourseSchedule courseInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionObj.Open();
            string get_number = "SELECT count(c_t_id) FROM course_teacher_table WHERE room_number = '" + courseInfo.RoomNumber + "' and class_days = '" + courseInfo.Days + "' and class_time = '" + courseInfo.ClassTime + "'";
            CommandObj.CommandText = get_number;
            CommandObj.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return '???'  

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ConnectionObj != null && ConnectionObj.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                ConnectionObj.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Does C# allow multiple queries then?

Comment: @EaterOfCode Not sure what that has to do with anything else here, but yes, it does.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn if not it's not a big danger because they can't start a second query. still not nice tho

Comment: @EaterOfCode But they _can_ start a second query.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn did you see that if statement at the start of my sentence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `CommandObj.ExecuteNonQuery();`, you can do this:

```
return Convert.ToInt32(CommandObj.ExecuteScalar());
```

You should use `ExecuteNonQuery()` only on update or insert statements. On queries which return single result, you can call `ExecuteScalar()` which returns `object` which you can convert to `int`.

On a side-note. I didn't see you concating the parameters. Don't do it that way. Otherwise, it is prone to sql-injections.

You have to use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: @Ikr, glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are several significant issues with that code beyond just getting a number back from the query.  The code below corrects most of them:

```
public int CheckMatch(CourseSchedule courseInfo)
{
     string get_number = 
          "SELECT count(c_t_id) " +
          " FROM course_teacher_table" +
          " WHERE room_number = @Room AND class_days = @Days AND class_time = @Time";

    //.Net works best when you create a brand new connection object for most queries
    using (var cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"))
    using (var cmd As New SqlCommand(get_number, cn))
    {
        //I'm guessing at sql column types here. Use the actual column types from the DB.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Room", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 5).Value = courseInfo.RoomNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Days", SqlDbType.Int).Value = courseInfo.Days;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = courseInfo.ClassTime;

        cn.Open();
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 
    }
}
```